# UIWebView magically underlines some kind of text

Tags: ios, uiwebview

If "Card.io" is written in the html string, UIWebview shows it as an underlined text in the below string.

```
<p>
    <strong>Card.io</strong>
    <br />The MIT License (MIT)<br />
    Copyright (c) 2013-2016 PayPal Holdings, Inc.<br />
    Permission is hereby granted, ...<br />
    The above copyright notice ...<br />
    THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" ... <br />...
    ......
</p>
```

If "Hello World" is written instead of "Card.io", UIWebview shows it as bold only not underlined as expected.

```
<p>
    <strong>Hello World</strong>
    <br />The MIT License (MIT)<br />
    Copyright (c) 2013-2016 PayPal Holdings, Inc.<br />
    Permission is hereby granted, ...<br />
    The above copyright notice ...<br />
    THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" ... <br />...
    ......
</p>
```

Why does UIWebView shows "Card.io" as underlined string? Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this issue unchecked "**Link**" property of `UIWebView`.

[image]

Now you get expected output as your requirement.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also Unchecked "Phone Number" property to remove underline from 2013-2016

Comment: Thanks for the "Phone Number" advice.

Answer (score 3):

"Card.io" is a URL so it will be detected directly.

Set [UIDataDetectorTypes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatadetectortypes) if you don't want to detect URL/Link.

```
webView.dataDetectorTypes.remove(.link)
```

Swift Version : 4.x

*In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class instead of using UIWebView.*

```
let theConfiguration : WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
theConfiguration.dataDetectorTypes.remove(.link)
let wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10), configuration: theConfiguration)
```

[image]

You can also do this changes through Inspectors

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove the blue link from selected links within the WKWebView, add this HTML tag before the "a href" tag:

```html
<STYLE>A {text-decoration: none;} </STYLE>
```

So the html to load in the WKWebView might be:

```html
<STYLE>A {text-decoration: none;} </STYLE>
<a href=\"https://www.stackoverflow.com\">
<div>This might be some text that you do not want a blue underline</div>
</a>
```

I did try adding style within the div tag, however the blue underline persisted.